# Finding all integer linear combinations subject to a constant contraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, integers

This question popped up in a project I'm working on and it wasn't immediately familiar as a linear algebra problem I've seen before.  So if this is a well known thing, apologies.  Just point me in the right direction.

Suppose I have a set of linear equations $ax_{1}=C , bx_{2}=C, ...$ where {$a,b,c...$} are integers.  It's of course easy to find $x_{1},x_{2}...$ etc.

What I would like to find is instead the set of all integers {$a', b', c'...$} such that $a'x_{1}+b'x_{2}+...=C$

Comment: All this is extremely well known... see "simultaneous Diophantine equations" and then poke around.

Comment: There's only a solution $(x_1, x_2, \dots)$ if $\gcd(a',b', \dots) \mid C$.  (I'm assuming you're taking some finite cut-off, of course.)